# Controller overriding in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm new to Zend Framework 2. I'm starting a project and I want its security being managed by ZfcAdmin, ZfcUser, ZfcUserAdmin and BjyAuthorize. The first thing I'm trying to do is modify the creation users' process. I want to be able to assign roles to a new user right after its creation.

The first problem I'm facing is when a user is created, the controller redirects me to the users' list page. I need to change this behaviour, I want to be redirected to the edit page, where I'll be able to choose N roles for the recently created user (that'll another war with entities...). I've chosen to override the UserAdminController (ZfcUserAdmin). That's what I've done to achieve that:

**1.** I load my administration module (MyAdministration) in the last place in *application.config.php*, 
in order to be able to override other modules' properties.

**2.** I override ZfcUserAdmin controller in *MyAdministration/config/module.config.php* in order to use mine:

```
(...)
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'zfcuseradmin' => 'MyAdministration\Controller\MyAdministrationController',
    ),
),
(...)
```

**3.** I've created the class
 *MyAdministration/src/MyAdministration/Controller/MyAdministrationController.php*

**4.** I've declared it to extend the ZfcUserAdmin one

```
namespace Administracion\Controller;
(...)
use ZfcUserAdmin\Controller\UserAdminController;

class AdministracionController extends UserAdminController {
(...)
```

**5.** I've overridden the createAction function to redirect to the edit page

```
(...)
public function createAction() {
(...)
return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/zfcuseradmin/edit/:userId', 
    array('userId' => $user->getId()));
}
(...)
```

That's where I don't know if I made it right. 
Searching the net and debugging I've learned that there's a class called InjectTemplateListener which transform the Controller's namespace into a path to the desired template. My controller 'is translated' to
**my-administration/my-administration/edit** which leads to nowhere, the templates belong to ZfcUserAdmin module. The right path is the one obtained by its controller (ZfcUserAdmin\Controller\UserAdminController):
**zfc-user-admin/user-admin/edit**

I also learned that template paths can be written manually. Those paths are ignored by
InjectTemplateListener. That's the approach I've used. In 
*MyAdministration/config/module.config.php* I've written:

```
(...)
'view_manager' => array( 
    'template_map' => array(
        'my-administration/my-administration/list' => __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/ZfcUserAdmin/view/zfc-user-admin/user-admin/list.phtml',
        'my-administration/my-administration/create' => __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/ZfcUserAdmin/view/zfc-user-admin/user-admin/create.phtml',
        'my-administration/my-administration/edit' => __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/ZfcUserAdmin/view/zfc-user-admin/user-admin/edit.phtml',
        'my-administration/my-administration/pagination_userlist' => __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/ZfcUserAdmin/view/zfc-user-admin/user-admin/pagination_userlist.phtml',
    ),
    (...) 
),
```

I'm not sure if that's the best way to achieve that. I feel there must be a better way to do that, instead of manually write template paths. I've found few things about overriding
Controllers, and no examples... Is this ok? Does anyone have a better approach to do the overriding?

Thanks!

Comment: I'll just have this as a comment since i don't know if it's all you need. The template that will be loaded is just on your namespaces domain. Meaning: `module/MyAdministration/view/my-administration/my-administration/edit.phtml`. I don't think you'll need to overwrite ZfcUsers template_maps, since they are of no relevance for the controllers that you overwrite. The follow the default mappings. But all in all, that's an 'i guess'

Comment: It's not require to write a new module to customize another module to your need, if the module provide option to configure redirection after registration try to use it else it would be better to modify the zfcusradmin controller directly to suit your need

Comment: @Sam: The problem is that there's no edit.phtml in my _module/MyAdministration/view/my-administration/my-administration/_. It only exists in _ZfcUserAdmin/view/zfc-user-admin/user-admin_. If I copy the file in my module, I think you're right, but I don't need it because I don't need to change its logic. Thanks!

Comment: @Raj: I'll give it a try. I've been fixed with ZfcUserAdmin's creation user way. This module hasn't got any property to configure redirection. I could try registration system in ZfcUser instead, which has properties that might suit my needs. About modifying ZfcUserAdmin, I prefer not to do changes in any module in vendor directory. Thanks!

Comment: I was just saying, IF you overwrite the controller, you need a new view-script, too. Otherwise you could return a ViewModel from that action that get's the template from the ZfcUserAdmin Module. like `$vm->setTemplate('zfc-user-admin/controllername/edit.phtml')` or something like that. As i don't know the modules configuration options, i can only speak for that approach ;) Generally Raj is right though, if there's configuration, use it, but you're aware of that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct the template name *can* be injected by a listener. That is under this single one condition: if there is no template name set.

So for this action the inject template listener injects the template name:

```
namespace MyModule;

class MyController
{
  public function myAction()
  {
    return new ViewModel;
  }
}
```

The template will be `my-module/my-controller/my-action`. However, if you set the template, the listener will be skipped:

```
namespace MyModule;

class MyController
{
  public function myAction()
  {
    $view = new ViewModel;
    $view->setTemplate('another-module/my-controller/my-action');

    return $view;
  }
}
```

You can see in the controller you are overriding the [returned data with the form is a simple array and not even a view model](https://github.com/Danielss89/ZfcUserAdmin/blob/master/src/ZfcUserAdmin/Controller/UserAdminController.php#L43-L47). The redirect plugin returns a Response object.

So, you check whether the return value is an array and if so, you set the template **explicitly**. This skips the listener to inject the template name:

```
namespace MyAdminModule;

use ZfcUserAdmin\Controller\UserAdminController as BaseUserAdminController;

use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Http\Response;

class UserAdminController extends BaseUserAdminController
{
    public function createAction()
    {
        $result = parent::createAction();

        if ($result instanceof Response) {
            // Old behaviour
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('zfcadmin/zfcuseradmin/edit/:userId', 
                                              array('userId' => $user->getId()));
        }

        // $result is array
        $view = new ViewModel;
        $view->setVariables($result);
        $view->setTemplate('zfc-user-admin/user-admin/create');

        return $view;
    }
}
```

Because you set the template name directly now, you can skip your manipulation of the template map in your config. This also enhances flexibility because you hard-coded the template paths with paths outside your module. You also have the option now to override the zfcUserAdmin template map in another module.

Comment: how about also writing a route such that, only for create action it invoke the UserAdminController and for all other it invokes zfcuseradmin controller, is it possible?

Comment: @Raj if you override the zfcuseradmin controller and you points the "invokable" to your class, this is already possible. Because `MyAdminModule\Controller\UserAdminController` overrides the ZfcUserAdmin controller, if you try to invoke `editAction()` on the `UserAdminController` you call in fact the action from the original controller.